# cherrypy.response.cookie with unicode key?

Tags: python-2.7, cherrypy

I have a cherrypy application that at various points sets cookies using the structure cherrypy.response.cookie[key]=value. However, I've found that if the object I use for key is a unicode string (even if it doesn't contain any non-ascii characters), I'll get an exception about translate() only taking one argument (2 given). I have to convert key to a non-unicode value to make it work. Is there any way I can fix this so I can just use the unicode strings directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cherrypy uses the standard library class `SimpleCookie` and therefore it depends on the
Python implementation.

This is an issue with Python 2, [that probably is not going to be fixed/changed](http://bugs.python.org/issue18012).

You can use Python 3 or use `str.encode`, of course you can also monkey patch the SimpleCookie class or something of that nature, but I think is a better idea to have more control on what are you putting in a cookie.